# Did I lose all my windows files?

Tags: 12.10

I decided to switch from windows 7 to Ubuntu 12.10. I had windows 7 on partition C: and other files (photos, music etc.) on partition D:. During installation I chose C: partition for Linux and checked box to encrypt drive. Now on Ubuntu I can't mount d: partition. It seems that partition doesn't exist. What to do? Did I lose all my windows files?

```
fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 120.0 GB, 120034123776 bytes  
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 14593 cylinders, total 234441648 sectors  
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes  
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes  
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes  
Disk identifier: 0x000a2484

 Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System  
  /dev/sda1   *        2048      499711      248832   83  Linux  
  /dev/sda2          501758   234440703   116969473    5  Extended  
  /dev/sda5          501760   234440703   116969472   83  Linux  

Disk /dev/mapper/sda5_crypt: 119.8 GB, 119774642176 bytes  
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 14561 cylinders, total 233934848 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/sda5_crypt doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu-root: 116.6 GB, 116551319552 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 14169 cylinders, total 227639296 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu-root doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu-swap_1: 3221 MB, 3221225472 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 391 cylinders, total 6291456 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu-swap_1 doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/cryptswap1: 3221 MB, 3221225472 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 391 cylinders, total 6291456 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0593f7a2

Disk /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 doesn't contain a valid partition table
user@user-N-A:~$ ^C
user@user-N-A:~$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 120.0 GB, 120034123776 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 14593 cylinders, total 234441648 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000a2484

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
    /dev/sda1   *        2048      499711      248832   83  Linux
    /dev/sda2          501758   234440703   116969473    5  Extended
    /dev/sda5          501760   234440703   116969472   83  Linux

Disk /dev/mapper/sda5_crypt: 119.8 GB, 119774642176 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 14561 cylinders, total 233934848 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/sda5_crypt doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu-root: 116.6 GB, 116551319552 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 14169 cylinders, total 227639296 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu-root doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu-swap_1: 3221 MB, 3221225472 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 391 cylinders, total 6291456 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu-swap_1 doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/cryptswap1: 3221 MB, 3221225472 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 391 cylinders, total 6291456 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0593f7a2

Disk /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 doesn't contain a valid partition tabl
```

Comment: Whenever the going gets rough partition-wise (independent of your OS) you may want to turn to [Terabyte Unlimited](http://www.terabyteunlimited.com/index.htm) with its excellent products and near-immediate support. Disclaimer: I'm not affiliated etc, just a long-time happy customer of theirs. Good luck!

Comment: If you used the "Replace windows..." option during installation, it deleted both the C: and D: partitions. Search this site for similar questions by others.

Comment: As noted by @user68186 I really think you told the installer to use the entire disk. There's no Windows partion in this disk.

Answer (score 0):

Since the partitions don't exist anymore you can't access your files via regular means.

But files that haven't been overwritten can potentially be recovered with the Command-line tool  Testdisk: https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/testdisk

Here's a How-To: http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/Undelete_files_from_NTFS_with_TestDisk